# NIntegrate failure

Tags: numerical-integration

```
NIntegrate[2*y*(Pi-ArcCos[x/y])*(Pi*(1-y)^2-Pi*x^2+x*Sqrt[(1-y)^2-x^2]\
)-2*Pi*y*(1-y)^2*ArcCos[x/(1-y)], {x, 0, 1/2}, {y, 1/2, 1-x}]
```

failed. `x=0`, `y=1` is a singular point, but even if I changed the range of `x` to `[0, 0.49999]`, it still fails.

Comment: `NIntegrate[
 2 y (Pi - ArcCos[x/y]) (Pi (1 - y)^2 - Pi x^2 + 
     x Sqrt[(1 - y)^2 - x^2]) - 
  2 Pi y*(1 - y)^2*ArcCos[x/(1 - y)], {x, 0, 1/2}, {y, 1/2, 1 - x}]` gives `0.0254131`. You need to put a space between variables. Look at the color while typing in code. Anything in blue color signifies a yet  undefined variable. More importantly, Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange.

Comment: Thanks, Syed. I copied your formula, and it returned back a formula like:
\!\(
\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(\[Integral]\), \(0\), 
FractionBox[\(1\), \(2\)]]\(
\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(\[Integral]\), 
FractionBox[\(1\), \(2\)], \(1 - x\)]\((2\ y\ \((x\ 
\*SqrtBox[\(
\*SuperscriptBox[\((y - 1)\), \(2\)] - 
\*SuperscriptBox[\(x\), \(2\)]\)] + \[Pi]\ \((
\*SuperscriptBox[\((y - 1)\), \(2\)] - ... I am using a student copy. I don't know if that's a problem.

Comment: are you integrating `{y, 1/2, 1-x}` or is this supposed to be `{y, 1/2, 1}` ?

Comment: Thank you Nasser, it's supposed to be {y, 1/2, 1-x}. Also, I found why I didn't see the result. I have to click on "full WlframAlpha results" to see the number. Otherwise I only see a formula. However if I type something a simpler Integrate(), it returns a number directly.

Comment: I think copying and pasting between various OS platforms/browsers and the use of `WolframAlpha` has clouded this question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Multidimensional numerical integration can very often be improved by analytically integrating as many coordinates as possible. Here we can integrate one coordinate analytically, and then integrate the other one numerically.

The integrand:

```
f[x_, y_] = 2*y*(Pi - ArcCos[x/y])*(Pi*(1 - y)^2 - Pi*x^2 +
  x*Sqrt[(1 - y)^2 - x^2]) - 2*Pi*y*(1 - y)^2*ArcCos[x/(1 - y)];
```

Integrate numerically:

```
NIntegrate[f[x, y], {x, 0, 1/2}, {y, 1/2, 1 - x}]
(*    0.0254131    *)
```

Interchange the integration order without changing the result:

```
NIntegrate[f[x, y], {y, 1/2, 1}, {x, 0, 1 - y}]
(*    0.0254131    *)
```

In the second form (with interchanged integration order) we can do the inner integral analytically:

```
g[y_] = Assuming[1/2 < y < 1,
  Integrate[f[x, y], {x, 0, 1 - y}] // FullSimplify]
(*    1/9 (π y (-15 - 12 π (-1 + y)^3 + 16 Sqrt[-1 + 2 y] +
      y (27 - 32 Sqrt[-1 + 2 y] + y (-9 + y + 12 Sqrt[-1 + 2 y])) + 
      12 (-1 + y)^3 ArcCos[-1 + 1/y]) + 
      4 y^2 (2 + (-4 + y) y) EllipticE[(-1 + y)^2/y^2] - 
      2 (-1 + 2 y) (3 + (-6 + y) y) EllipticK[(-1 + y)^2/y^2])    *)
```

Now do the outer integral numerically:

```
NIntegrate[g[y], {y, 1/2, 1}]
(*    0.0254131    *)
```

More precision:

```
NIntegrate[g[y], {y, 1/2, 1}, WorkingPrecision -> 100]
(*    0.02541311192794056570658058206266048123896002325014901687532205739489299245044718028628092486091772098    *)
```